# Moving from local VM to Azure Cloud?

Tags: azure, vmware

our webpage Contao 4.4 is running on a local machine with a vm-ware VM.
Now I was thinking of using a Docker container to install the CMS. But than I was thinking of taking the whole VM an migrate it into our Azure Cloud to use the load balacer and CDN feature.

How easy is that migration?

THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Azure Site Recovery for exactly that migration of a VM from VMware to Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/migrate-tutorial-on-premises-azure

[image]